# Docker Swarm services not accessible from host on Windows Server 2019

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

*This is a cross-post from [the Docker Forums](https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-access-published-ports-on-loopback-in-windows-server-2019/72009) in an attempt to get a response faster*

I am working on setting up a Dockerized service at my company that will need to be load balanced and behind an IIS reverse proxy (for TLS offloading and multi-homed capabilities). The service itself appears to be working fine (I can access it from my workstation computer directly, or through another server’s IIS reverse-proxying to the Swarm manager server). The issue is that I am unable to access the service from the Swarm manager itself. It is running on `0.0.0.0:8080` and I have tried `localhost:8080`, `127.0.0.1:8080`, and `<server's static IP>:8080` to no avail.

If I start a standalone container running `microsoft/iis` with a published port, I'm able to access that, so this appears to be specific to Swarm.

I read that published Swarm ports were not available on the loopback adapter prior to Windows Server 2019, but this machine is running the latest 2019 build (Windows Server Version 1809, Build 17763), so I was under the impression that I should be able to access this service on loopback. Ideally we should not have to run IIS on a separate server to reverse-proxy to the containerized service. What gives?

This is the `docker-compose.yml` file we're using:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  api:
    image: our.registry.server/ourimage:${OUR_IMAGE_VERSION:-latest}
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 5s
        failure_action: rollback
        monitor: 10s
      rollback_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 2s
        failure_action: continue
        monitor: 10s
      restart_policy:
        delay: 3s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 45s
    healthcheck:
      test: curl -f http://localhost/healthcheck || exit 1
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 10s
```

Comment: what is the command you use to create the service?

Comment: @DaiBok `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml stack-name`. I will post a minimal `docker-compose.yml` as I'm using it.